# Conditional configuration of a CPQ Product as Bundle

Tags: cpq, cpq-plugins

We have a complex CPQ scenario that I would appreciate your inputs.

We have **1 CPQ product (single record)** that:

- For some types of quotes should appear as a **bundle** (with many product options and features preselected)
- For some other types of quotes it should appear by default not as a Bundle but as **1 single quote line** without the additional options to be visible at all

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create two products.  Assuming that whoever is selling the product will know if it should be a configurable bundle with options or standalone.  They would then select the appropriate SKU depending on their use case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196075)